# KeyError: 392 upon trying to decode CAN message using dbc file?

Tags: python, can-bus

I am trying to decode CAN messages from a device using the manufacturer's provided dbc file. I am using Python 3.8.5. To load/set up the dbc file, I have:

```
import can
import cantools

self.bus = can.interface.Bus('slcan0', bustype='socketcan',bitrate=250000)
listener = can.Listener()
listener.on_message_received = self.callback
self.dbc = cantools.database.load_file(dbc_file_path,strict=False) #need strict=False or it raises errors for overlapping signals for some reason
```

in the callback function I have:

```
def callback(self, can_msg):
    decoded = self.dbc.decode_message(can_msg.arbitration_id, can_msg.data)
```

The script runs, but as soon as it receives a CAN message from the device, it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                       
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cantools/database/can/database.py", line 385, in decode_message                                                                                            
    message = self._frame_id_to_message[frame_id_or_name]
KeyError: 392
```

Any idea what might be going wrong? I have googled and found similar errors on stack overflow, but they don't seem to be exactly the same, and the solutions they propose don't fix my issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The device was sending CAN messages with arbitration_ids that were not listed in the dbc file, and thus giving a Key Error. A Key Error is where you try to reference a Key in a Dictionary that does not exist. 392 was the unrecognized ID. I worked around this by adding a try/exception statement around my
`decoded = self.dbc.decode_message(can_msg.arbitration_id, can_msg.data)` line, and then investigating why the dbc file wasn't prepared for this particular message id.